# Axios Interceptors just working after page reload

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to send the `Authorization` header inside of all requests, when user is logged in my application.

but, whatever i do, it does not work.

Here is my `axios` instance and interceptor code.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import storage from '@/services/storageService'

const user = storage.getObject('currentUser')

export const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/api',
})

http.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if(user){
        console.log(user)
        config.headers.Authorization = user.token
    }
    return config
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    return Promise.reject(err)
})
```

in my modules i'm importing the `http` instance like this

```
import { http } from '@/http'

export const getItems = () => {
   return http.get('items').then( response => response.data)
}
```

So, clarifying, this code above works, but the header is not present on my request.

To get the `interceptor` working i need to **force a page reload**.

Anyone know how can i avoid this?

Comment: each code in your model will run once only,even though has many imports,so if(user) always be false when first run,you can move const user = storage.getObject('currentUser') into the interceptors.

Comment: Thanks @jacky it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem following @jacky's tip. Now my code runs as following.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import storage from '@/services/storageService'

export const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/api',
})

http.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    let user = storage.getObject('currentUser')
    if(user){
        console.log(user)
        config.headers.Authorization = user.token
    }
    return config
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    return Promise.reject(err)
})
```

Comment: I just had the same problem and this helped me a lot!. Thank you so much!!